# Anaconda to Miniconda and $PATH

Tags: macos, anaconda, conda

I am completely new to python and bash. I uninstalled Anaconda using conda clean and deleted the `.anaconda_backup` in my home directory. I opened the `.bash_profile` and did see 
`export PATH="/Users/XXXXX/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"` and few other instances of `$PATH` appended.

My `.bash_profile`

```js
# added by Anaconda3 5.3.1 installer
# >>> conda init >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$(CONDA_REPORT_ERRORS=false '/Users/XXXXXXXXXX/anaconda3/bin/conda' shell.bash hook 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    \eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/Users/XXXXXXXXXX/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
# . "/Users/XXXXXXXXXX/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"  # commented out by conda initialize
        CONDA_CHANGEPS1=false conda activate base
    else
        \export PATH="/Users/XXXXXXXXXX/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
# <<< conda init <<<

##
# Your previous /Users/XXXXXXXXXX/.bash_profile file was backed up as /Users/XXXXXXXXXX/.bash_profile.macports-saved_2019-01-19_at_19:04:16
##

# MacPorts Installer addition on 2019-01-19_at_19:04:16: adding an appropriate PATH variable for use with MacPorts.
export PATH="/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH"
# Finished adapting your PATH environment variable for use with MacPorts.

# added by Anaconda3 2019.10 installer
# >>> conda init >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$(CONDA_REPORT_ERRORS=false '/Users/XXXXXXXXXX/opt/anaconda3/bin/conda' shell.bash hook 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    \eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/Users/XXXXXXXXXX/opt/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
# . "/Users/XXXXXXXXXX/opt/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"  # commented out by conda initialize
        CONDA_CHANGEPS1=false conda activate base
    else
        \export PATH="/Users/XXXXXXXXXX/opt/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
# <<< conda init <<<

# >>> conda initialize >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$('/opt/anaconda3/bin/conda' 'shell.bash' 'hook' 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/opt/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/opt/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
    else
        export PATH="/opt/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
# <<< conda initialize <<<
```

However, I didn't actually understood the part related to removing the Anaconda path from `.bash_profile` given in the manual. I ran echo $PATH again after uninstalling Anaconda and it looks exactly like before when i had Anaconda. 
  `/opt/anaconda3/bin:/Users/XXXXX/opt/anaconda3/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/Users/XXXXX/anaconda3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`

I plan to install miniconda and create an environment for learning data science. I am trying to force myself to get more and more acquainted to terminal

Is it still safe to go ahead and install the Miniconda? How do I remove Anaconda path from `.bash_profile`? Will I be still able to open python by just typing the python command? or I would need to add a different path to access python after installing python through miniconda?

Comment: Maybe you could share your bash_profile and we can tell you waht needs to be removed?

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I just added the .bash_profile.

Comment: Looks like two previous Anaconda installs and a separate run of `conda init`. Conda does have a `conda init --reverse` option, which is supposed to clean up old edits to RC/profile files (e.g., `.bash_profile`). You could install MiniConda first, then run that followed by a fresh `conda init`. Or more directly, you could manually remove everything between each `# >>> conda ...` and a `# <<< conda ...` block (including those lines). Then install the MiniConda after. (I.e., probably what those directions are recommending).

Comment: How did you uninstall Anaconda?